# Enforce native resolution on Linux Mint 18

Tags: xorg, nvidia, resolution, edid

My graphics card is Nvidia GT 440 and I'm using the nvidia binary driver v384.130 on Linux Mint 18. I have a Dell U2518D which has a native resolution of 2560x1440@60Hz and the problem is that the resolution options in Mint settings get as high as 1920x1080 for 16:9. After doing some research on the net, trying a lot of different xorg.conf file configurations, I have failed to fix the problem and found out that maybe I should create a custom EDID file?

So using the get-edid tool I get this:

```
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 4
1 potential busses found: 5
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 5
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DELL U2518D"
    ModelName "DELL U2518D"
    VendorName "DEL"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 14 of 2018
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 550 310
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 30-90
    VertRefresh 56-76
    # Maximum pixel clock is 250MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1600x1200, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1920x1080, 60Hz

    #Extension block found. Parsing...
    Modeline     "Mode 16" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline     "Mode 0" 241.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync 
    Modeline     "Mode 1" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline     "Mode 2" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1082 1087 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
    Modeline     "Mode 3" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline     "Mode 4" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline     "Mode 5" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline     "Mode 6" 27.027 1440 1478 1602 1716 480 484 487 525 -hsync -vsync interlace
    Modeline     "Mode 7" 27.000 1440 1464 1590 1728 576 578 581 625 -hsync -vsync interlace
    Modeline     "Mode 8" 25.200 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline     "Mode 9" 27.027 1440 1478 1602 1716 480 484 487 525 -hsync -vsync interlace
    Modeline     "Mode 10" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline     "Mode 11" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline     "Mode 12" 27.000 1440 1464 1590 1728 576 578 581 625 -hsync -vsync interlace
    Modeline     "Mode 13" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline     "Mode 14" 74.250 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1082 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
    Modeline     "Mode 15" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline     "Mode 17" 147.18 2048 2096 2128 2208 1080 1083 1093 1111 +hsync -vsync 
    Modeline     "Mode 18" 74.25 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline     "Mode 19" 58.23 2048 2096 2128 2208 1080 1083 1093 1099 +hsync -vsync 
    Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 16"
EndSection
```

So below the "#Extension block found. Parsing..." line, I can see that Mode 0 is the one I want (the native resolution), which is present here but not in the Linux Mint's resolution options and also that there is an option for the Preferred Mode to be Mode 16 which is actually a 1920x1080 resolution and this is the recommended option from Linux Mint.

I would also like to point out that the same was happening on Windows 7 and I fixed it by creating a custom resolution in the nvidia control panel.

Any suggestions?

I'm also posting the xorg.conf file as it is right now, which is in its original state.

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 384.130  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-03)  Wed Mar 21 04:09:03 PDT 2018

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option "ModeValidation" "AllowNonEdidModes"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```